# Linq Where Lambda Super Slow

Tags: c#, linq, list, where-clause

I have a list of a custom class with only 6 properties. There's a field called "status"

I have them in a Generic List

```
 List<House> hList = GetHomes(); //Holds 204 instances of House
 int count = hList.Where(x=>x.status == "sold").ToList().Count();
```

Doing this returns 3 which is correct but it takes 10 seconds to do so.

Is there a faster way?

Comment: Can you post the code for GetHomes()

Comment: You can skip .ToList(), but I don't think that the second line of code is the problem.
Is 'status' really a field or a property?

Comment: Are you doing anything in the `status` getter?

Comment: your problem not in this two line of code

Comment: BrokenGlass that's it! I'm calling another function in the getter to set the value.. I forgot.. duh

Comment: Off-topic, but you could count like this:  `int count = hList.Count(x=>x.status == "sold");`

Answer (score 4):

If you only need the count, you can do this:

```
var count = hList.count(x => x.status == "sold");
```

This will prevent iterating 3 times (for the where, then tolist, then count)

Comment: The `Where` won't actually iterate over the list.  Linq uses deferred execution.  The first time it will iterate is on `ToList`, then again on `Count`.  But still a good point.